# How to notice which statement's line that report error in Xcode's console window?

Tags: xcode, exception

I'm using Xcode in my development work. Sometime I debug my application and it report error via console window. Like example below:

`2009-12-10 22:13:58.968 Sunrise Cam[1023:207] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '* -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)'

2009-12-10 22:13:58.971 BowMaker [1023:207] Stack: (
    35423323,
    36959497,
    35507259,
    35507098,
    1830089,
    1425959,
    51192,
    4390579,
    5707381,
    5715274,
    5714271,
    4430810,
    4371321,
    4412756,
    4401311,
    31769264,
    31768687,
    31766726,
    31765818,
    31799352,
    35209810,
    35206751,
    35204168,
    45553549,
    45553746,
    4112387,
    10456,
    10310
)`

In Visual Studio, they report which line raise the exception. How can I do this with Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Xcode 3.2.x on Snow Leopard (Mac OS X 10.6.x), the menu command **Run > Stop on Objective-C Exceptions** should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Robert is right, though you won't see the line number on the console log.  You need to go to the call stack trace and click on the first line you recognise.